# When I used android:layout_below="@+id/username" my test box disappears into the top left of my screen

Tags: android-studio

When I use android:layout_below="@+id/username" the text box labeled password is supposed to be under the username box but instead it disappears into the top left.[Without adding "username" to id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unECD.png)[When adding "username" to id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZKSQ.png)

The text box with password is supposed to just be below the username box.